# images vs views(button, radiobutton....) in Android

Tags: android, image

Why do we need for images to create different files for the different densities and not for a Button View from Android for example? A button view under the hood is an image, right?

Thanks

Comment: Android does it for you.

Comment: And why not for the images?

Comment: Ok, but when we talk about to create distinct images for different densities on Android, we do it for keeping the size of the image or to keep the quality?

Comment: we do it for keeping the quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an image has a very specific width and height, in pixels. A button, and other widgets, don't have any instrinsic dimension, they can be of any width and height and are mostly drawn with commands (or xml attributes that are translated into commands), such as lines or arcs.